# Problema con consulta en mysql condicionales <>

Tags: mysql

Estoy realizando un select para obtener los registros entre dos fechas pero cuanto uso la condicional de (>) o (<) no me funciona ya que no me muestra nada de informacion solo con (=) si me muestra los registros pero los que son iguales a las fechas y asi no me sirve, me podrian orientar que estoy haciendo mal.

```
SELECT roles_turno_emp.nomina, 
       empleado.nombre, 
       empleado.ruta, 
       roles_turno_emp.turno, 
       roles_turno_emp.f_inicial, 
       roles_turno_emp.f_final 
       FROM roles_turno_emp 
       INNER JOIN empleado on empleado.nomina=roles_turno_emp.nomina 
       WHERE roles_turno_emp.F_INICIAL > "2018-12-13" AND 
       roles_turno_emp.F_FINAL < "2018-12-21"
```

Comment: hay datos que cumplan con esas fechas no??? al mismo tiempo???

Comment: tienes que hacer DATE("2018-12-13")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta agragando un BETWEEN  asi:

```
SELECT roles_turno_emp.nomina, 
       empleado.nombre, 
       empleado.ruta, 
       roles_turno_emp.turno, 
       roles_turno_emp.f_inicial, 
       roles_turno_emp.f_final 
       FROM roles_turno_emp 
       INNER JOIN empleado on empleado.nomina=roles_turno_emp.nomina 
       WHERE roles_turno_emp.F_INICIAL 
      BETWEEN "2018-12-13" AND roles_turno_emp.F_FINAL  "2018-12-21"
```

Comment: eh.. esto no funciona.. un between va contra un solo campo..

Comment: Estas haciendo un between entra dos tabla distintas inicial y final